# RegEx for pattern in c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am still learning RegEx so I need some help on this one.

Rules are as below:

- Min/Max Length of string: 1-5
- String has to be a whole word
- String can contain: A-Z and/or a-z and/or 0-9 or combination of both only (e.g. _ - . * are not allowed)

Examples:

```
12345 – allowed
Os342 – allowed
2O3d3 – allowed
3sdfds dsfsdf – not allowed
Sdfdf.sdfdf –now allowed
```

Comment: Regex in which programming language/utility, please?

Comment: I am doing it in C#. But why doesn't matter?

Comment: C# RegEx tester: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Because every language has slightly different regexp syntax. Which is one reason I probably can't help you much, I don't know C#.

Comment: There are slightly different regex implementations in different languages. Even Visual Studio itself is using non-.NET regex implementation in it's find/replace dialog:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000633.html

Comment: I think RegEx is useful but hard. And very hard to test...

Comment: Not sure which one to accept now...

Comment: First entry by time with correct answer.

Comment: I think Rubens was in the lead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
string input = "12345";
bool match = Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[a-z0-9]{1,5}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Without ^ and $, the regexp tester he gave me matched "12345" of "123456"; apparently that should be rejected though.

Comment: And you were right about those other chars. I deleted my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I used RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, so will not differ a-z from A-Z (as OP said is working with C#). But you can remove it and to add A-Z if you wish

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]{1,5}$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}$
```

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` specifies the ranges allowed
- `^` specifies start of string
- `$` specifies end of string
- `{1,5}` indicates minimum and maximum number of characters for the range

Comment: You want to do `1,5` to catch strings shorter than 5 chars too, I think.